# Show that any epimorphism from the ring $(Z, +, .)$ onto itself is an isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Show that any epimorphism from the ring $(Z, +, .)$ onto itself is
an isomorphism.

I think by the term epimorphism means an onto homomorphism.

Firstly, I assumed, $\phi:Z\to Z$ such that $\phi$ is an onto homomorphism.

I tried to prove $\phi$ is an isomorphism by showing that $I(\phi)=U=\{0\}.$

Now, $\phi(0)=0$ as $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Now, if $\exists a\in Z$ such that $\phi(a)=0$ then $U=\{$ set of multiples of  $a\space \}.$

Next, I claimed that $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x\in Z$.

But I am not able to prove the claim.

If I couldve' proven the claim then I can get a contradiction as $\phi$ is onto. But till now, I haven't been able to do so.

Comment: What can you say about $\phi(1)$?

Comment: Does your definition of ring homomorphism require to map identity to identity? If so, the only homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ (don't even need to assume it to be surjective) is the identity, which is clearly an isomorphism.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh! $\phi(1)=1$ which means $\phi$ must be an identity mapping and hence an isomorphism. Am I correct? If what I said is correct, I will proceed to delete this post.

Comment: Correct (assuming that in your book rings have a $1$, and $\phi(1)=1$ for all homomorphisms of rings. There are some authors who don't require this (I do, but this is something teachers of algebra don't agree on).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wait, in the book Topics in Algebra by IN Herstein there was an exercise as : If $R$ is a ring with  $1$ and $f$ is a homomorphism of $R$ onto $R',$ $f(1) $ is the unit element of $R'.$ So, I think this is more of a theorem than a convention, if I understood your last comment correctly.

Comment: I think it’s worth noting that “epimorphism” does not always simply mean “surjective.” In the category of commutative rings with unit, the ring map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism (in the category-theoretic sense) but it definitely isn’t surjective. In this case it’s not an issue but in some cases it can be a problem.

Comment: @GEdgar I think you should take a  look at this:
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798439/show-that-any-epimorphism-from-the-ring-z-onto-itself-is-an-isomorphis#comment10204205_4798439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is an epimorphism it follows that $\phi(1)=1$. We shall prove that $\ker\phi=\{0\}$. Let $z\in\ker\phi$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $z>0$. Hence,
$$0=\phi(z)=\phi(1+\overset{z)}{\ldots}+1)=z\phi(1)=z\cdot 1=z.$$
And we are done.

Answer (score 2):

If the kernel $U$ of $\phi$ isn't $\{0\}$ then the image of $\phi$ is isomorphic to the finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/U$, so $\phi$ isn't surjective. So the kernel is $\{0\}$, so $\phi$ is both injective and surjective, hence an isomorphism.

Comment: How could you say, that the ring $\Bbb Z/U$ is finite? I did not quite get it.

Comment: $U$ is just $k\mathbb{Z}$ for some $k$ and the quotient ring is $\mathbb{Z}_k$.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks! +1 from me.